# Does anyone know of a way to use a variable as the filename input into xlsread?

Tags: string, matlab, variables, xlsread

EDIT: I figured out the problem.  claim was listed as a cell class.  Used cell2mat to convert it to char, and the code worked.  Thank you, everybody!

I have a string variable set to a file pathway/location. I would like to use this variable as the input to the xlsread function, but Matlab tells me that xlsread cannot take a variable input.  I'm having lots of trouble figuring whether a workaround is even possible. Can someone help me out?

```
 function C = claimReader()

 inp = csv2struct(['C:\Documents and Settings\nkulczy\My Documents\085 Starry Sky\','Starry_Sky_inputs_vert.csv']);
 inputTitles = [{'Output_Dir'};{'Claimz'};{'Prodz'};{'Fault_Locations'};{'Fault_Type'};{'Primary_Failed_Part'};{'Part_Group'};{'Selected_SEAG'};{'Change_Point'};{'Date_Compile'};{'Minimum_Date'}];

 claim = inp.(cell2mat(inputTitles(2)));  %returns a file path/location string

 C = csv2struct(claim);

 end


 function Out = csv2struct(filename)

 %% read xls file with a single header row

 [~, ~, raw] = xlsread(filename);

 [~ , ~, ext] = fileparts(filename);

 if ~strcmpi(ext, '.csv') %convert non .csv files to .csv, so blanks stay blank
      filename=[pwd,'tempcsv',datestr(now,'yymmddHHMMSSFFF'),'.csv'];
      xlswrite(filename,raw);
      [~ , ~, raw] = xlsread(filename);
      delete(filename);
 end

 if size(raw,1)==11 && size(raw,2)==2 %transpose SS inputs (must      match dimensions of input matrix EXACTLY!!!)
     raw = raw';
 end

 nRow = size(raw,1);
 nCol = size(raw,2);
 header = raw(1,:);
 raw(1,:) = [];

 end
```

Comment: You're doing something wrong.  Post your code.

Comment: It's definitely possible, look a the examples in the docs: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html. Post code because you've most likely just made a small error somewhere

Comment: I made some edits, does that help?

Comment: Yeah, I figured out the problem.  I was inadvertently referencing the 1x1 cell, rather than the string inside it.  I'm an extreme amateur when it comes to matlab, and the learning curve is rather steep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the syntax as following and there shouldn't be any problems:

```
pathname = 'c:\...\filename.xlsx';
A = xlsread(pathname);
```

Edit: regarding your code:

I can't see where you define `filename` - you should pass `claim` (it contains the desired path?) to the `xlsread`-function. 
Probably you get a cell with chars. So your input needs to be `claim{1}`

Comment: You are renaming a built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation of `xlsread`, the first output (`yourNums`) will only return the numerical values in the sheet. `txt` will only return text. `rawData` will return the raw data in the sheet.

```
flNm = 'c:\myFolder\myFile.xlsx';

[yourNums, txt, rawData] = xlsread(flNm);
```

Update after TS:

`claim` is a cell array. So you need to pass `claim{1}` in order to let it be a string.

Comment: If I manually insert the filepath and location, [~,~,raw] gives the the raw data just fine.  My error is:

`??? Error using ==> xlsread at 122`
`Filename must be a string.`